# Como conectarme a un WEb Service Rest

Tags: php, json, webservice, web, php5

Buen día.
Tengo que conectarme a un Web Service Rest para hacer validaciones de CURP con php, tengo la url, el usuario y contraseña del WS pero no he logrado encontrar la forma en la que debo conectarme, adjunto la forma en que debo enviar los datos para poder verificar, espero me puedan apoyar ya que soy nuevo en esto y no se absolutamente nada, ya busque y no encuentro mucho el como conectarme, enviar los datos y recibir, me apoyarían bastante orientándome como conectarme y a partir de ahí poder hacer pruebas de envió y recepción de datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Sabes qué tipo de peticiones acepta el webservice?

Comment: Y qué te responde POSTMAN cuando ejecutas ese request?

Comment: {
    "@statusOper": "EXITOSO",
    "@message": "LA OPERACION SE EJECUTO.",
    "@TipoError": "",
    "@CodigoError": "",
    "@SessionID": "m5QTXu6tQdEv1d1qBThx6PgDazT1G-AWbLGUOCi3P0UobJG_NU-M!1529049445!1512153476781",
    "CURP": "LOMF590827HDFPTR01",
    "apellido1": "LOPEZ",
    "apellido2": "MATEOS",
    "nombres": "FERNANDO",
    "sexo": "H",
    "fechNac": "27/08/1959",
    "nacionalidad": "MEX",
    "docProbatorio": "1",
    "anioReg": "1960",
.....
}

Comment: Esto en caso de que el curp sea valido

Comment: Entonces te funciona. No veo cuál es el problema

Comment: Pero quiero saber como implementarlo en php, debo hacer un formulario donde pido la curp, la mando a validar y en caso de que sea correcta, me traigo datos como el nombre, apellido, lo que quiero saber es como hacer eso en PHP!

Comment: Puedes probar con PHP con CURL, yo hago peticiones POST con JSON a urls del gobierno. Pero tengo otra peticion, sé que debo crear otra pero creo que es justo aqui está la respuesta, necesito me ayudes tambien @Israel Gutierrez de algun manual del WebServices de IPN, en que URL se mandan las peticiones, tengo usuario y contraseña, pero no encuentro donde enviar las peticiones, si me puedes proporcionar los url o algun manual, la variables a enviar, con gusto los hago y te los envío ya hecho aquí

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es lo primero.. desde tu controller debes usar la función de php llamada file, esta se encarga de ejecutar ese webservice y traer el resultado.. como el tuyo trae un array json debes hacer el siguiente procedimiento.

```
    $array_json = file('https://api.plataforma.ipn.mx/publico/general/secure/renapo/curp/consultar');
```

Una vez obtenido el webservice en la variable, lo que próximo a realizar es utilizar una función más para descomponer este array json y quede como un array normal.

```
    $array_normal = json_decode($array_json[0],true);
```

Si lo que quieres obtener un valor de ese array utilizas la funcion array_column() así:

```
    $extraer_columna = array_column($array_normal , 'CURP');
```

y luego

```
    $curp = $extraer_columna[0];
```